# how to make an output statement "virtual"?

Tags: c++

I know that the output statement cannot be virtual, but how do I make it work like a virtual method?

for example this code :

**base class :**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Car {
private:
    int speed;
    double size;
public:
    Car(double size = 2.5, int speed = 180) {
        this->speed = speed;
        this->size = size;
    }

    int getSpeed() const{
        return this->speed;
    }

    double getSize() const{
        return this->size;
    }
};
```

**heir from Car :**

```
class BMW : public Car{
private:
    int speed;
    double size;
public:
    BMW(double size, int speed) {
        this->speed = speed;
        this->size = size;
    }

    ~BMW();
};

class Audi : public Car {
private:
    int speed;
    double size;
public:
    Audi(double size, int speed) {
        this->speed = speed;
        this->size = size;
    }

    ~Audi();
};

class StateCars {
private:
    int speed;
    double size;
public:
    StateCars(double size, int speed) {
        this->speed = speed;
        this->size = size;
    }

    ~StateCars();
};
```

**and and the question is how to change it correctly so that it works for all heirs in the past**

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Car& state) {
    out << "Speed " << state.getSpeed() << endl;
    out << "Size " << state.getSize() << endl;
    return out;
}
```

my main:

```
int main() {
    Car car;
    Audi audi(1.5, 220);

    cout << car << endl;
}
```

how can i output for example **Audi** data as in mine because i have compilation error :

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccItPoaT.o:car.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `Audi::~Audi()'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccItPoaT.o:car.cpp:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `Audi::~Audi()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**expection in console :**

```
Size 1.5
Speed 220
```

I hope I explained clearly

Comment: A major problem is that all child classes have their own set of `speed` and `size` variables, this are unrelated to the `Car` variables of the same name. Remove them from all child classes, and make them protected in the parent `Car` class.

Comment: The error message you've shown appears to be simply a matter of having *declared* destructors for `BMW` and `Audi`, but not having *defined* them.

Comment: i changed,and anyway i have an error @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Side note: you may need a `virtual` destructor in `Car`. At the moment you don't, but if you need to `delete` a `Audi` when using it as a `Car`, the virtual destructor is vital.

Comment: did not help @user4581301

Comment: For a polymorphic type, in the base class add `virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const { out << "blah"; }` and then in the derived classes override that as needed.  And change the stream inserter to `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Car const& car) { car.print(out); return out; }`

Answer (score 3):

You declare the different destructors, but you never *define* (implement) them.

Either add an empty body:

```
class Audi : public Car {
    Audi(double size, int speed) {
        this->speed = speed;
        this->size = size;
    }

    ~Audi()
    {
        // Empty body for destructor
    }
};
```

Or simply omit the destructor altogether:

```
class Audi : public Car {
    Audi(double size, int speed) {
        this->speed = speed;
        this->size = size;
    }

    // No destructor here at all    
};
```